# Can't connect to LAN world

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to connect to my sisters LAN world server, but it's not showing up when I go to friends (it's supposed to be under the friends online tab). We are connected to the same Internet, we both have the multiplayer options selected, and we are not far apart (like 5ft away from each other). I'm not sure if it's because I'm using my iPhone, and she's using a Kindle Fire tablet. When I go into one of my worlds, and she goes to friends it shows up on her screen; but why not mine?

I am playing version 15.0.

Comment: Are you sure you guys are both on the same version of MCPE? Just make sure you guys are both running the latest version of the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just read the customer reviews. Apparently, lots of people are having problems with connecting with a Kindle Fire 2nd Gen.

https://www.amazon.com/Cannot-another-both-Kindle-Fire-/forum/Fx2YO8IV8UND36O/TxXNYLY2E88G6Q/1?asin=B00992CF6W

If you have the first gen Kindle Fire, you may be able to connect.